# How to loop through a list of strings in r

Tags: r

I have some bloated code in R which I'm trying to streamline. I'm trying to read spreadsheets into a dataframe and then transpose each one.

I have a list as follows

```
var <- c("amp_genes.annotated.BLCA.txt","amp_genes.annotated.BRCA.txt")

for (i in var) {
  var[i] <- readWorksheet(wk, sheet="var[i]", header=T)
  var[i] <- as.data.frame(var[i])
  var[i] <- t(var1[i][3:ncol(var1[i]),])
}
```

The sheet = line has to have double quotes around the string variable.

This just tells me I have an unexpected }

Comment: R is not a macro language, you can't do `"var[i]"` - it will literally pass the text `var[i]` exactly as shown, with no interpretation. You want `sheet=i` as `i` will contain the text of the `var` vector, as in `for (i in c("a","b") ) print(i)`

Comment: So in order to call the correct sheet I need to put double quotes around the text in the readworksheet line. How do I then append the double quotes to i?

Comment: what's in your `var` vector, are those sheet names? Or are they names you wish to give to your output (delimited) files? Also, note that you are overwriting your `var` iterator at the first line inside your loop, which in not a good idea!

Comment: The var vector is sheet names which I then hope to give my outputted dataframe. I think I've changed the code to avoid the overwriting?

Comment: wk is the name of the worksheet yes. And yes var is the name of the sheets

Comment: You're still overwriting your iterator. `var` will take value `amp_genes_...` at its first iteration, as a character variable. Then you put it in something else. An iterator should be left alone for the whole duration of the loop!

Comment: `var` is a vector, you cannot put a `data.frame` as first element but if you want you could (instead of your loop) do something like `sapply(var, function(x){readWorksheet(wk, sheet=x, header=T)` and you'll get a list of data.frame corresponding to your sheets

Comment: I've put an answer, maybe this makes sense, maybe not, it's hard to say without seeing your excel workbook, its worksheets and their content.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this; not sure it will work as I don't have your spreadsheets, but give it a try and let me know... And maybe if it doesn't work right out, it can hopefully unblock you wherever you're stuck.

```
library(XLConnect)
wk <- loadWorkbook("workbookname.xls")

sheetnames <- getSheets(object = wk)

content.tr <- list()

# To access sheets by their names
for (sheetname in sheetnames) {
  content <- readWorksheet(wk, sheet=sheetname, header=T)
  content.tr[[sheetname]] <- t(content[3:ncol(content),])
}

# To access sheets by their position
for (pos in c(1,2) {
  content <- readWorksheet(wk, sheet=i, header=T)
  content.tr[[sheetname[i]]] <- t(content[3:ncol(content),])
}
```

To access the dataframes:

```
names(content.tr)
spreadsheet1 <- content.tr[[1]]
spreadsheet2 <- content.tr[[2]]
```

Comment: Ok with this is get Error in 3:ncol(content) : argument of length 0. Is this because sheetname when passed to sheet needs to be in double quotes

Comment: I corrected a few problems with the code, hopefully you have better luck with it now.

Comment: Changed a couple of typos above. Now its almost perfect. As an educational point how then do I refer to the dataframe throughout further code I want to put into the loop. Do I refer to it as content.tr[[sheetname[i]]] ? I will want to rename the first column for example as I go so should this then be content.tr[[sheetname]][,1]  = c("chr")

Comment: Yes that would be perfectly acceptable! Although you could just do your transformations on `content` and then put the thing in the list as the last operation inside the loop.

Comment: ...except for the fact that it doesnt relabel the column name, it puts 'chr' in every single row. How would I make it just change the column name?

Comment: smth like `colnames(content)[1] <- "chr"` maybe?